# get value of ion-rangeslider in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, smartadmin, ion-range-slider

I am using `ion.rangeslider` in my angular application and it displaying fine.
But how can i get the value of the `silder` and i need to update min and max values of the slider dynamically.

I have seen some of the questions in SO like this [ion-rangeslider not getting displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342502/ion-rangeslider-not-getting-displayed) and [ion RangeSlider: customize grid in case of custom values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227894/ion-rangeslider-customize-grid-in-case-of-custom-values). some of other solutions but they  didn't help me.

my html is as follows

```
<div class="form-group">
      <input ionSlider id="sliderData" type="text" data-min="2000" data-from="2000" data-max="2800" data-type="single"
        data-step="5" data-prefix="$ " data-prettify="false" data-hasgrid="true" (onChange)="ionSliderForValues($event)">
    </div>
```

**Component**

```
ionSliderForValues(event:any){
    console.log(event);
  }
```

is there any other methods to get the value of the slider or any chance to get in angular way. suggest me you wil be well rewared, thank you.

Comment: go with this https://github.com/PhilippStein/ng2-ion-range-slider, i dont know how you implemented the jquery script in angular, but i hope this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this, with the help of [ng2-ion-range-slider](https://github.com/PhilippStein/ng2-ion-range-slider) as @Ravikumar suggested. I felt there was no answer related to this in SO. That's why i am posting my answer here for some other who is stuck in same problem

> For npm installation and Imports, do follow ***ng2-ion-range-slider*** documentation

**component.html**

```
   <div class="form-group">
            <ion-range-slider #sliderElement type="single" [min]="myMinVar" [max]="myMaxVar" grid_num="10" prefix="$ "
              [from]="currentValue" (onChange)="myOnChange($event)"></ion-range-slider>
   </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
  myOnChange(event: any) {
     console.log(event.from);
  }
```

you can change the min and max `range` of the slider dynamically by adding variables in component and assign them as attributes.