# Ion.RangeSlider change status in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm using [Ion.RangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/) in Angular7 project. When I want to update the slider I use following code:

```
var instance: any = $(".irs-hidden-input").data("ionRangeSlider");

        instance.update({
            from: Math.floor(Math.random() * (10)),
            to: 10
        });
```

The $ sign is like to jQuery mode, How I can read data from @ViewChild?

Thanks for taking the time and explain it.

Comment: `How I can read data from @ViewChild?` is there any child kind of relation between your code

Comment: Yes, There is. @ViewChild("slider") slider: ElementRef;  and  <input #slider ...> But I can't read it.

Comment: I catch the error: this.slider.nativeElement.data is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend to use [**`ng2-ion-range-slider`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ion-range-slider) instead of [**`Ion.RangeSlider`**](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/). Because i was faced same kind of issues to catch the update and change events of **`Ion.RangeSlider`** in Angular then i found this one.

> For npm installation and Imports, do follow **`ng2-ion-range-slider`** documentation

**`ng2-ion-range-slider`** now optimized for easy use as an importable Angular 2 Module and installable using npm and it is built on top of **`Ion.RangeSlider`** so that we can access all the features of it in easy way.

```
<ion-range-slider #sliderElement
          type="double"
          [min]="myMinVar"
          max="100"
          from="28"
          from_min="10"
          from_max="30"
          from_shadow="true"
          to="40"
          to_min="40"
          to_max="90"
          to_shadow="true"
          grid="true"
          grid_num="10"
          prefix="Weight: "
          postfix=" million pounds"
          decorate_both="false"
          (onUpdate)="myOnUpdate($event)"
          (onChange)="myOnChange($event)"
          (onFinish)="myOnFinish($event)"></ion-range-slider>
```

I have answered same kind of issue [get value of ion-rangeslider in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479526/get-value-of-ion-rangeslider-in-angular) check it once..